# Is it bad practice to deploy a script alongside the product?

Tags: software-distribution

I am working on an embedded software project, whose output is an executable which will run on a linux device, using C++.

The app uses peripherals. Some kernel modules are not loaded when the system is powered on. Hence, I am forced to load them manually by `modprobe`. Currently, I am using a script to accomplish this and I am using a service to run this script after boot. As a result, I assume I have to distribute the script and the service file alongside the app.

Is distributing script a bad practice? The reason why I think is this there will be updates to software and app can already handle updating itself. However, to update the service file and the script is not handled and although it can be handled it does not feel right.

If this is not a bad practice, how can I load modules inside the code. First idea that comes to mind is to use `system()` function. I'd welcome any other suggestions.

Comment: Just to add a bit of context, Git source code is ~35% shell scripts. As far as I know, all the "plumbing", is C code, i.e. the tools for writing to/reading from the database, where the "porcelain", is primarily shell scripts, i.e. the command line tools you normally interact with (if you use the native git tooling).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let me say you are asking the wrong question. You do not decide for or against a certain solution because it could be a "bad practice". You decide for or against it because the solution works (or doesn't work) in a reliable fashion.

So to answer the question you should have asked: you can deploy a software written in any programming language and form you like as long as the platform provides a run time environment for the software. For a shell script, this means you have to be sure the platform needs to provide something like a certain version of a shell environment (like bash). And there is nothing inherently in wrong when the distributionn of a software contains multiple files.

> However, to update the service file and the script is not handled and although it can be handled it does not feel right.

The problem with upgrading scripts and configuration files is often that you have to make a clear decision who is responsible for changing them, or if it is forbidden to change them afterwards manually:

- the deployment process / installer procedure (so finally you as the one who develops it)
- the user or admin of your software / the one who installs the software.

**Make sure this does not get mixed up**. If users of your software are not supposed to change anything in those scripts and files, insert a clear comment statement at the beginning of the file that these files are subject to an update process and will be overwritten with the next version, so any manual change will get lost.

If the users of your software are supposed to change something in those scripts and files to adapt it to their environment, allow them to make it in a copy of the original files and tell them the original files work only as a template, and these templates may be overwritten with the next update.

To your comment: yes, "ease of use" for installations of updates may be another consideration. Giving the "responsible person" just one executable file which does the necessary steps automatically is definitely simpler and less error prone than letting them follow a manual which file has to be put where. So

- trying to find a solution which does not need any script or configuration file is definitely a way which should be explored
- if that's not possible, creating helper files automatically at the right place is also fine
- if an installation requires manipulating existing configuration files this can become a trade-off. When the config file has a strict syntax, this may also be automated, but depending on the complexity of the task, it may be more reliable to let a user/admin do the steps manually.

If you follow these guideline, there should be no problem in updating the files/scripts by you.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I should've included this in the question: I won't be updating the application executable and scripts **on devices**. The reason is the fact that these devices will be in use and they will be spread out the country. Users won't be able to change anything. The person responsible for updating may not know where to put these files e.g., putting dummy.service file under /etc/systemd/system. Maybe I should write another script that puts files where they're supposed to be? Also, if it wasn't clear, there is no installer since device has no GUI or CLI.

Comment: @Sonder: when no updating happens,  there is no problem to solve. But you wrote "The person responsible for updating may not know where to put these files" - so there is some update procedure? Then think about how to make the update process as smooth and simple as possible for the "responsible person". Putting a file in a specific folder is something which should not be hard to automate.